# Autohotkey, How to use shortcuts with #L and not lock the screen?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm moving from linux to windows, and autohotkey is saving my life. one thing that i'm having trouble is with the functionality:

I'd like to emulate the arrow keys if i press HJKL (vim keys)  with the left flag (windows) key pressed.

i have this in my autohotkey script:

```
LWin::Send {LWin}
<#h::Send {left}
<#j::Send {down}
<#k::Send {up}
<#l::Send {right}
; tried to use "lWIn & l", "$<#l", "$LWin & $l"...
```

everything works, except the flag+L. i mean, it works, as i get a left key down event just fine. but the screen also locks.

the manual says `$` avoids the original key event, but it's locking the screen still.

any hope on working around that?

Answer (score 2):

You'l have to disable this one in the registry: WARNING actual path May be version dependent

```
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, DisableLockWorkstation, 1
```

Here is another article: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disableenable-lock-workstation-functionality-windows-l/